# Pass Values to Event Receiver

Tags: 2010, development

I have an event reciver which sends an email when a listitem is being deleted.
When the user clicks on the item, a popup prompt is displayed on the page and the user is requested to give a reason for deleting. How do I pass the text entered on the prompt window to item deleting?

Comment: Why don't you remove the event receiver and just have that page send the email and delete the item?

Answer (score 3):

You could add a hidden field to the list called something like "Delete Reason" then update that via Javascript prior to the delete.  When your event receiver fires, you only need read the value from the field prior to deleting the item.

Answer (score 2):

Hi I assume that you make the prompt through javascript. So the only way I see, is to have a helperlist where you input the text through javascript and ID (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185011(v=office.14).aspx)  and then reads it and deletes it in the event receiver.